# Not able to listen to a socket event in ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

> If I am trying to call the socket.on outside the component, It is working but when I use it in useEffect() It is not working?

````
import ChatBubble from "../components/Chatbubblebot";
import io from 'socket.io-client'

let data = [];

function Messagelist({ sendMessage }) {
  data.push(sendMessage);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000")

    socket.on("admin",(payload) => {
      console.log("payload",payload);
      data.push({who:"him",message:payload})
    })
    
  })
  let list = () => {
    console.log("sendMessage",sendMessage.length);
    if (data === undefined && sendMessage.length === 0) {
    } else {
      return data.map((e) => <ChatBubble who={e.who} message={e.message} />);
    }
  };
  return <ul>{list()}</ul>;
}

export default Messagelist;```
````

Comment: So this statement ` console.log("payload",payload);` is only printed when you put the `socket.on` outside the component but `io.connect` inside the useEffect ?

Comment: @TusharShahi  No when the whole socket code is outside the component it is working

Comment: Try adding a dependency array in your useEffect. CUrrently the socket connection code runs after every render. Maybe that is the issue. Is your server ready by the time this component render?

Comment: Yes, I added that but the socket.on is not running. @TusharShahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the socket variable outside component.

```
var socket;
```

And then in the component useEffect:

```
socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000")
```

Also,

the `let data = [];` should not be defined like that.

It should be a state variable of the component like below:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

And when you get new message from socket:

```
socket.on("admin",(payload) => {
      console.log("payload",payload);
      let _data= data;
      _data.push({who:"him",message:payload});
      setData(_data);
 })
```

Comment: Okay, I did as you said but it is still not working @Mutuza

Comment: From the doc, the socket is connected with "const socket = io("https://server-domain.com");" instead of what you have written "const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5000")" 

So give it a try without the .connect()

Comment: Okay tried removing .connect and still it is not working. @Murtuza